# Could someone post instructions for how to create a modallly presented tab bar controller?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, modal-dialog

I'm just trying to make the most basic tab bar controller that gets presented modally. I want to use nibs, as opposed to doing it all programatically, but I really don't understand Interface Builder:

Why can't I drag a tab bar controller into my veiw?

Why does IB create another "window" when I drag a TBC to the document window?

Why are there 2 view thingys in the same nib?

Why do I get this message (crash) when I try to present the modal view: "nib but the view outlet was not set" ?

How do you remember which little connections you need to make in IB, other than the obvious ones you reference in the code?

Is there an IB tutorial out there that goes beyond just the most basic pre-made application templates and actually explains what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I drag a tab bar controller into my view?

Because only other views can be dragged onto views. A view controller is not a view.

> Why does IB create another "window" when I drag a TBC to the document window?

Because every view controller has its own main view. If you double click a view controller in IB, its view opens.

If you really want to create all controllers from a NIB file, do it like this:

1. Create a fresh empty XIB file called "TabBarController.xib". It contains nothing but the entries for File's Owner and First Responder.
2. Drag a UITabBarController into this XIB. Ignore the view that gets opened (you can close it).
3. Configure the tab bar controller according to your needs, especially by dragging as many UIViewController objects (or UIViewController subclasses) onto the tab bar controller as you have tabs. If these child view controllers should be instances of your custom view controller subclasses, make sure to set their classes accordingly in the Inspector.
4. For each child controller of the tab bar, create another XIB file in Xcode, this time using the View XIB preset. Let's call these "ChildController1.xib", ... Open all of them in IB and set their File's Owner class to the class of the corresponding child controller (i.e., UIViewController or a subclass). Then connect the views in these XIB to the view outlet of File's Owner. Configure these views as you need them (by adding the actual UI elements of the child views and possibly connecting other outlets if necessary).
5. Close the child XIBs and return to TabBarController.xib. For each child controller, open the Attributes Inspector and set its NIB Name attribute to "ChildController1", "ChildController2", ... Then close the XIB.
6. In your code:

   ```
   NSArray *nibFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TabBarController" owner:self options:nil];
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = [nibFile objectAtIndex:0];
   [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
   ```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I just see the original view with no modal view. To the items in step 4 happen automatically when you create viewcontroller subclasses and let xcode create the nibs for you? How do you connect 'views in these XIB to the view outlet of File's Owner

Comment: In TabBarController.xib: what should be connected to the file's owner->view port. I tried connecting it to the TabBar (view) item under the tab bar controller. Now a modal view opens with a tab bar that stretches to fill the entire screen. I thought maybe I could try to connect file's owner->view to the TabBarController->view, but it won't let me do that.

Answer (score 0):

I broke down and just configured the TabBarController without using Interface Builder. The more I'm getting into iPhone development, the more I'm realizing that IB is bad, and to not use it except for the rare components with absolute layouts. In this case, all you would gain by using it would be the icons and titles on each tab. IB doesn't really provide any earth-shattering visualization on that.

I really wish nibs rendered down into some readable text format, so you could always drop to the code to understand what was going on, but that's not the case, so I'll gladly add 6 lines of code to make my program not crash